# Filter based on 3rd character of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have list of data exported from Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 into `sheet1`. I would like to filter those items based on the value of `J2:Jxx`. But it is dependent on the 3rd character of `J2:Jxx`.

### Example

If `J2`as the value ee2abc, do I want the values of `C2`, `H2` and `J2`showing in `sheet2` cells `A2:C2`. 

Same goes for `sheet3`where I want it to filter on the values 1 & 3 as 3rd character. 
 
The value doesn't always start with "EE" en the characters after, do change too. It's only the 3rd character that cycles between 1, 2 & 3.

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

### What I have tried

I've played around with advanced filtering and tried with the If function but those didn't seem to do the work for me.

```
=IF(J2="=??2*";B2;)
```

This resulted in all 0.

I prefer to use a function if possible since I have no experience with VBA.

Comment: Easiest way is to add a helper column to your source data table where you extract 3rd character, e.g. `=MID(J2,3,1)`, then you can easily filter on it.

Comment: I would like to automate the copy to sheet2 & sheet3 as much as possible and not copy them by hand since this has to happen for every month. The full source sheet contains about 300 rows each.

Comment: Do you have entries where first 2 characters are not "EE"?

Comment: yes I do. same goes for 1&3. So it's like `##2*`

Comment: First of all, you should ensure that your criteria range does not overlap the table range.  This usually means starting your table down some rows (e.g. row 5).  So for the advanced filter formula criteria, to filter on the third character in column J something like `=MID(J6,3,1)="2" (where J6 is the first row of data in your table).  Note the quotes around the number, since the value returned by the `MID` function will be a string.  But it would probably be simplest to automate this in `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`) since you could also automate the hiding of the unwanted columns.